# Increased initrd image size in 5.19.0

Tags: grub2, kernel, initramfs, initrd

After I upgraded from 5.19.0-23 to 5.19.0-26, my initrd.img size grew a lot:

| Size | Update |
| --- | --- |
| 49M | initrd.img-5.19.0-23-generic |
| 131M | initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic |

I already have 2 workarounds from [Bug 1842320](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1842320) so that I can boot without the *error: out of memory* issue.  Nonetheless, what caused the large size change if compression and build settings remain the same? If interested, the workarounds that allow me to boot are as follows

1. Try to load some but not all modules in initramfs by changing line 20 of */etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf* to `MODULES=dep`
2. Compress the initrd.img to a higher zstd compression by changing line 196 of */usr/sbin/mkinitramfs* to `zstd) compress="zstd -q -19 -T0" ;;`
3. And of course updating grub

Comment: Did you update the initrd itself after your changes?

Comment: Yes, updated initrd after changes

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the increase in initrd, I don't believe there is a care about the size increase to many. This may be because many have a clean install of kinetic which increased the size of the *boot*  partition which also helps with not worrying about the size increase.

Other errors also showed up for people as shown in [Bug 1842320](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1842320) which were of larger concern. The workarounds I shared and others were used until a general fix was released for grub-efi-amd64, grub-efi-amd64-bin, and grub-efi-amd64-signed in version 2.06-2ubuntu14.1.

For note, grub-efi-amd64-signed is set to 14.1 while the other 2 are updated to 14.2 which also breaks the install preventing grub-efi-amd64-signed from installing.  I'll open a question about it in case there needs to be a bug filed.